# how to print in a specific log file using a logger without printing in the supervisord log file in a tornado application

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, tornado, supervisord

I'm currently developing a Tornado application made from different indipendent modules.

The application run using supervisord, so right now, every time I use

```
logging.info()
```

the log is printed on the supervisor log and I'm ok with that.

The problem is that now the supervisor log file is full of very different stuff from different modules and very hard to read, so I now want that every module use a specific logger and every logger write on a different file.

So I created the logger:

```
def set_log_config(filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0):
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
    create_folder(directory)

    app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application.fiscal")

    handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when=when, interval=interval, backupCount=backupCount)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(module)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%y%m%d %H:%M:%S')

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    app_log.addHandler(handler)
    app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return app_log

fiscal_logger = set_log_config(
        '/home/dir/Trace/fiscal/fiscal_module_{:%Y-%m-%d}.log'.format(datetime.now(), when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=21)
    )
```

The logger works, it write on the specific file, but it also always write in the supervisor log file and I don't understand why.

So my question is: how can I write on the specific file when I use the fiscal_logger.info and on the supervisor file when I use logging.info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I explain why your logger also writes to the supervisor log file.

Writing to supervisor log file means there is a `StreamHandler` in your current logger chain.

`logging.info` basically equals to `logging.getLogger().info` which means it uses `root` logger. Additionally, `logging.xxx` will automatically add a `StreamHandler` to `root` logger if `root` has no handler.

And by default logs will be propagated along logger chain(For example, `"tornado.application.fiscal"`'s logger chain is `root -> tornado -> application -> fiscal`). So `fiscal_logger`'s log is propagated to `root` logger and processed by `root`'s `StreamHandler`. That's why you see those logs in the supervisor log file.

---

To fix this problem, you have two options **at least**.

1. Do not use `logging.xxxx` any more. Instead, use another named logger such as `console_logger`.
2. Set `fiscal_logger.propagate` to `False`.